# One half spacing in tables

Tags: tables, line-spacing

What is the easiest way to get one and a half line spacing in all my tables? I have the `setspace` package loaded, if that helps. The relevant bits of my preamble currently read:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[font={onehalfspacing}]{caption}
```

This gives me one half spacing for my body text and the captions of figures/tables/etc.

Comment: `\extrarowheight`? Of course, would be easier with an MWE.

Comment: As far as I can tell, \extrarowheight adds a fixed amount of space, so is not a general solution that works for all text sizes.

Comment: Something similar is ````\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{X}```` where X is some number. 1 appears to be the default which reproduces single spacing. I don't know what X needs to be to reproduce one half spacing, only that 1.5 isn't it (too big).

Comment: According to `setspace`, it is  ~1.25, depending on the font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on what "onehalfspacing" entails. If it's equivalent to `\setstretch{1.5}`, you should try `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`.

If your `tabular`-like envrionments are located inside `table` environments, and if you're using the terminology of the `setspace` package and your main font size is `10pt`, you should try `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}`; for `11pt` and `12pt` main font sizes, you should use values of `1.213` and `1.241`, respectively.

In the screenshot below, the left-hand and right-hand `tabular` environments are typeset before and after a `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` is executed, respectively. (The default value is `1`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%define a dummy table
\newcommand\mytab{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{lll}
   \hline
   a & b & c\\
   \hline
   d & e & f \\
   \hline
   h & i & k \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\mytab
\quad
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\mytab

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you clarify how you got the numbers 1.25, 1.213, etc?

Comment: @Ulysses - I found these numbers inside the file `setspace.sty`, in the section that defines `\onehalfspacing`.